# my c++ program is working ambigously.number is automatically changing into hexadecimal..pleease healp

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

my c++ program is working ambiguously.number is automatically changing into hexadecimal..please help

```
int main() {
    int t=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
        {
        int Q;
        string A,B,C;
        cin>>Q;
        cin>>hex>>A;
        cin>>hex>>B;
        cin>>hex>>C;

        string bit_A,bit_B,bit_C;
        bit_A=con(A);
        bit_B=con(B);
        bit_C=con(C);
        int k=0;
       for(unsigned i = 0; i != bit_B.length(); ++i)
               {

           if(bit_B[i]=='0' && bit_C[i]=='1' && bit_A[i]=='0'  )
               {

               bit_B[i]='1';
               k++;
               continue;
           }
           if(bit_C[i]=='0')
               {
               if(bit_B[i]=='1')
                   {
                   bit_B[i]='0';
               k++;
               }
               if(bit_A[i]=='1')
                   {
                   bit_A[i]='0';
                   k++;
               }
               continue;
           }
       }
        if(k>Q)
            {
            cout<<"-1";
            continue;
                }

       cout<<"value 0f k is"<<k<<endl;
         for(unsigned i = 0; k<Q && i != bit_A.length(); ++i)
               {
             if(bit_A[i]=='1' && bit_B[i]=='1')
                 {
                 bit_A[i]='0';
                 k++;
             }
             if(bit_A[i]=='1' && bit_B[i]=='0' && (Q-k)>=2)
                 {
                 bit_A[i]='0';
                 bit_B[i]='1';
                 k++;
                 k++;
             }
         }


         }



        cout<<std::uppercase<<hex<<todeci(bit_A)<<endl;
        cout<<std::uppercase<<hex<<todeci(bit_B)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here k value hacve changed automatically to hexa decimal which i cant figure out y?can anyone please help?
1
12
CAF7028FD
59B5AC1CE
CAF1B7B7F
for this input you will see k showing as B in output

Comment: Hex is a matter of number representation, not of actual value.

Comment: This looks like homework / competitive coding. These kinds of questions usually aren't helpful to other users. Besides, please provide your research and an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `std::hex` to a stream, it tells that stream to read or write numerical data as hexadecimal numbers.

```
cout << hex << 16 << endl;
// Outputs "10".

int i;
cin >> hex >> i;
// If you enter "10", reads "16".
```

If you want to switch the stream back to decimal, pass it `std::dec`, like so:

```
int j = 0x10; // 16
cout << dec << i << endl;
// Outputs "16".

int k;
cin >> dec >> k;
// Reads "10" as "10".
```

You can also do this for octal (base-8), using `std::oct`.  This follows the same rules as the above two modifiers.

---

Note that after passing a modifier to a stream, it will retain that state until passed another modifier.

```
int x = 0xFF; // 255
int y = 0x3E; //  62
cout << hex << x << endl; // Outputs "FF".
int z;
cin >> z;
cout << y << endl;        // Outputs "3E".
cout << dec << x << endl; // Outputs "255".
cin >> z;
cout << y << endl;        // Outputs "62".
```

Notice that both times `y` was output to `cout`, it used the same formatting that was specified before outputting `x`, instead of reverting back to decimal output.  Due to this, if you want to output a single value as hexadecimal, and later values as decimal, it can be useful to write it like this:

```
cout << hex << 16 << dec << endl;
```

---

Note that there is no associated modifier for binary output.  If you want to output a number in binary, the simplest way is to create and output a temporary `std::bitset`, like so:

```
#include <bitset>  // For std::bitset.
#include <climits> // For CHAR_BIT.

unsigned int q = 0xF3;
cout << bitset<sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT>(i) << endl;
// Outputs "00000000000000000000000011110011".
```

Similarly, if you want to read a binary number, you can use `std::bitset` like so:

```
unsigned int r = 0;
std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT> bitReader;
cin >> bitReader;
r = static_cast<unsigned>(bitReader.to_ulong());
// Reads binary value, then converts it to an unsigned integer type.
```

Note that `CHAR_BIT` is the system's byte size; as such, multiplying by `CHAR_BIT` isn't strictly necessary (it's usually safe to assume it's 8 bits), but will make your code more portable (by allowing it to compile properly on systems where the byte size *isn't* 8 bits).